# React Native, setting value of item in state incorrectly

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              message: "..",
            };
    }
    render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.textInput}>

              <TextInput onChangeText={(message) => this.setState({message})} placeholder="Enter your message..." style={styles.text}/>

              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.submit}>

                <Text ref="message" onPress={this.submit}>Submit</Text>

              </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>

          </View>
        )
    }

    loadData(){
      AlertIOS.alert(this.state.message);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.loadData()
    }
    submit(){
      AlertIOS.alert(this.state.message);
    }
```

When `loadData` is first called, it shows the current value of message: ".."

When my `submit` function is called, it throws an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.message')`

I'm assuming that it is my onChangeText attribute that's setting message to undefined, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` isn't bound correctly in `submit()`

In your constructor, try adding the line:

`this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);`

Comment: So anytime I want to use `this` to access my state I need to bind each of my functions?

Comment: @user3890432 I believe this is only necessary when you use a function as a callback, such as you are with `onPress={this.submit}`. You can also do one-time bindings like `onPress={this.submit.bind(this)}`, which is useful if you're only going to use the callback in one location, as it looks like you're doing.